# Change namespaces at once

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Is there a way to change the namespaces at once of all classes in a directory / all classes in a solution?

If I now decide to `refactor` a bit and therefore move a few classes in a directory, then `Resharper` will warn me that the namespace is out of sync with the directory.

I only have the option to go through all the moved classes one by one and change the namespace accordingly. It's a bit of monkey work and I was wondering if there isn't an easier way to do this at once.

Comment: If al your classes have the same namespace which have to be renamed you can right click the namespace of one class and click rename. F2 will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy to accomplish in ReSharper.

Right click on your solution, go to `Refactor .. Adjust Namespaces`

Comment: heeeeeeelllll no! hah that is a welcome surprise! excellent! glad i finally asked this question! thx a lot! (will accept in 6min, not allowed to yet)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to change the namespaces at once of all classes in a directory / all classes in a solution?

You don't need resharper for this - Visual Studio has a comprehensive [find and replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165349.aspx) that will let you do so for all files in a solution.

The feature also allows you to use wildcards or regular expressions (though some of the syntax is specific to Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Resharper`. Visual Studio has [**`Search and Replace`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165349.aspx) options for this. `Resharper` has also search & replace options looks like this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use `Find and Replace` feature. But, `Refactor` works fine too.